# Modernizr yepnope conditional callback only when false

Tags: javascript, modernizr, yepnope

I'd appreciate your thoughts and advice on the best way to do this. Id like to execute a tiny script — not worth loading — if modernizr test is false. This solution looks a bit clunky.

```
        Modernizr.load({
            test: Modernizr.inlinesvg,
            yep : 'js/funky-svg-animation.js',
            complete : function () {
                if (!Modernizr.inlinesvg){
                    console.log('stuff to do when false');
                }
            },
        });
```

EDIT:
Based on comments, would this be an efficient approach:

```
        if (Modernizr.inlinesvg){
            $(body).append('<script src="js/funky-svg-animation.js"><\/script>')
        } else {
            console.log('stuff to do when false');
        }
```

Or are there problems with this approach?

Answer (score 2):

In Modernizr you have `yep` and `nope` so if the browser you are testing doesn't support the feature you need, with nope you can do your stuff.

```
Modernizr.load({
      test: Modernizr.inlinesvg,
      yep : 'js/funky-svg-animation.js',
      nope : 'path/to/your/script.js'
      },
  });
```

where 
*path/to/your/script.js* is just:

```
console.log('stuff to do when false');
```

This is the default behavior of Yenope, that is supposed to load external resources if needed.

Comment: And then you could just remove the conditional in the script.js since it will only be executed in the nope-states (I assume this because I have no experience with Modernizr/yepnope)

Comment: yes that is right, yenope will load the script only if that feature is not available in the browser.